Fetch rows from PostgreSQL with rearranged words similar to a given string
I want to retrieve all rows from a PostgreSQL database that contain sentences similar to a provided string. The sentences in the database can have their words in any order (rearranged). How can I implement this functionality in Python?
I attempted to use the fuzzy matching functionality available in PostgreSQL, but it didn't produce the desired results for me.
Let suppose this is the Question
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Expected rows from the PostgreSQL Database with column name sentence:
create table test(txt) as values
 ('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
,('over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps')
,('jumps over the lazy dog quick brown the fox')
,('lazy dog jumps the quick brown fox over the');

The answer should return all 4 of the above rows.

So the selected rows must match all the word in the input, in any order? Can there be missing or extra words?

and you want to do it in python ? you can select it in postgres like that:select
*
from tbl_test
where string_to_array(tbl_test.sometext ,' ') @> string_to_array('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog',' ')


I attempted to use the fuzzy matching functionality available in PostgreSQL, but it didn't produce the desired results for me.

It looks like fairly simple full text search can produce the results you described:
demo at db<>fiddle
alter table test add column txt_tsv tsvector 
  generated always as (to_tsvector('english',txt)) stored;

select*,plainto_tsquery('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
       ,ts_rank( txt_tsv
                ,plainto_tsquery('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'))
from test
where txt_tsv @@ plainto_tsquery('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');




txt
txt_tsv
plainto_tsquery
ts_rank




the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
'brown':3 'dog':9 'fox':4 'jump':5 'lazi':8 'quick':2
'quick' & 'brown' & 'fox' & 'jump' & 'lazi' & 'dog'
0.7722033


over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps
'brown':7 'dog':4 'fox':8 'jump':9 'lazi':3 'quick':6
'quick' & 'brown' & 'fox' & 'jump' & 'lazi' & 'dog'
0.7806461


jumps over the lazy dog quick brown the fox
'brown':7 'dog':5 'fox':9 'jump':1 'lazi':4 'quick':6
'quick' & 'brown' & 'fox' & 'jump' & 'lazi' & 'dog'
0.7722114


lazy dog jumps the quick brown fox over the
'brown':6 'dog':2 'fox':7 'jump':3 'lazi':1 'quick':5
'quick' & 'brown' & 'fox' & 'jump' & 'lazi' & 'dog'
0.780132



You can combine the full text search above with pg_trgm and fuzzystrmatch to help with misspelled words and other types of problematic input.
Hard to tell why (and how) your attempt didn't work because you didn't show it. While you could technically compare these with fuzzy matching, it would be expensive and unreliable.
Using Levenshtein as an example: it's establishing the similarity by rearranging individual characters - it doesn't respect word boundaries, doesn't do stemming and considers large rearrangements expensive. In effect, random anagrams can be closer to the target than actual language.
select txt,levenshtein(txt,'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
from 
(select txt from test union 
 values ('e qnrbu rzhwd eox hfmla oueoyt sjocpk i tgv')
       ,('ghnyw uco orptz x jum be dir vsfeklah qotoe')
       ,('m tkeui  bpqwez uonol j vrd xorhthegosy fca')
       ,('ttekqueg  znoh oyo udxh vcb pjwmeslra  riof')
       ,('dhikp xtofblnorgu tj  qum seyver wheoza c o')
       ,(' lheafxc  zoon bmoiujgqdptrs ovr twe ue yhk') )_
order by 2;




txt
levenshtein




the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog (that's the input)
0


dhikp xtofblnorgu tj  qum seyver wheoza c o
28


lheafxc  zoon bmoiujgqdptrs ovr twe ue yhk
28


ghnyw uco orptz x jum be dir vsfeklah qotoe
29


e qnrbu rzhwd eox hfmla oueoyt sjocpk i tgv
29


ttekqueg  znoh oyo udxh vcb pjwmeslra  riof
30


m tkeui  bpqwez uonol j vrd xorhthegosy fca
30


lazy dog jumps the quick brown fox over the
30


over the lazy dog the quick brown fox jumps
36


jumps over the lazy dog quick brown the fox
36



